# Calculating distances in TSPLIB

Tags: python, distance, traveling-salesman, lib

Hello i have a problem with calculating distances between cities from tsp library: http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/countries.html. I have this set of data (cities in djibouti): http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/tsp/world/dj38.tsp. I used this function to calculate distaces in this QaA here: http://comopt.ifi.uni-heidelberg.de/software/TSPLIB95/TSPFAQ.html. i programed this in python and now it looks like this, here is my code:

```
cityCoords = {
    1:(11003.611100,42102.500000),
    2:(11108.611100,42373.888900),
    3:(11133.333300,42885.833300),
    4:(11155.833300,42712.500000),
    5:(11183.333300,42933.333300),
    6:(11297.500000,42853.333300),
    7:(11310.277800,42929.444400),
    8:(11416.666700,42983.333300),
    9:(11423.888900,43000.277800),
    10:(11438.333300,42057.222200),
    11:(11461.111100,43252.777800),
    12:(11485.555600,43187.222200),
    13:(11503.055600,42855.277800),
    14:(11511.388900,42106.388900),
    15:(11522.222200,42841.944400),
    16:(11569.444400,43136.666700),
    17:(11583.333300,43150.000000),
    18:(11595.000000,43148.055600),
    19:(11600.000000,43150.000000),
    20:(11690.555600,42686.666700),
    21:(11715.833300,41836.111100),
    22:(11751.111100,42814.444400),
    23:(11770.277800,42651.944400),
    24:(11785.277800,42884.444400),
    25:(11822.777800,42673.611100),
    26:(11846.944400,42660.555600),
    27:(11963.055600,43290.555600),
    28:(11973.055600,43026.111100),
    29:(12058.333300,42195.555600),
    30:(12149.444400,42477.500000),
    31:(12286.944400,43355.555600),
    32:(12300.000000,42433.333300),
    33:(12355.833300,43156.388900),
    34:(12363.333300,43189.166700),
    35:(12372.777800,42711.388900),
    36:(12386.666700,43334.722200),
    37:(12421.666700,42895.555600),
    38:(12645.000000,42973.333300)
    }

def calcCityDistances(coordDict):
    cities = list(coordDict.keys())
    n = len(cities)
    distances = {}
    latitude = []
    longitude = []
    RRR = 6378.388;
    PI = 3.141592;

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        cityA = cities[i-1]
        latA, longA = coordDict[cityA]
        deg = int(latA)
        Min = latA - deg
        latitude.append(PI * (deg + 5 * Min / 3) / 180)
        deg = int(longA);
        Min = longA - deg;
        longitude.append(PI * (deg + 5 * Min / 3) / 180)

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
            q1 = cos(longitude[i-1] - longitude[j-1]);
            q2 = cos(latitude[i-1] - latitude[j-1]);
            q3 = cos(latitude[i-1] + latitude[j-1]);
            key = frozenset((i, j))
            distances[key] = {}
            dist = RRR * acos(0.5 * ((1.0 + q1) * q2 - (1.0 - q1) * q3)) + 1.0  
            distances[key]['dist'] = dist
            distances[key]['pher'] = init_fer
            distances[key]['vis'] = 0

    return  distances 

distances = calcCityDistances(cityCoords)
```

My problem is that the distances calculated in this algorithm are off mark in huge scale. average lenght of one route between cities is 10 000 km and the problem is that the optimal TSP route is 6635. you can imagine that when i apply this to my Ant Colony System algorithm the result is around 110 000 km. this is really different from 6 thousand. Can someone explain what am i doing wrong please ?

Comment: I was just running in the same issue. I believe the official formula is wrong: "latitude[i] = PI * (deg + 5.0 * min / 3.0 ) / 180.0". The part 5.0*min/3.0 is to convert the minutes in decimals. 60 Minutes would be 1 decimal. This would be the case if not divided by 3.0 but by 300. So the correct formula is "PI * (deg + 5.0 * min / 300 ) / 180.0"

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the distance calculation listed in the TSP FAQ.  Here's the resource I've used in the past: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

He gives two great circle distance calculation methods.  Neither one looks like the one TSP provided.  But, they both produced a distance that seemed to match reality (that Diksa and Dikhil are about 31k apart).

The input data is in 1000ths of a degree, and I'm not sure if the conversion to radians given takes that into account.

Here's an implementation that might give you better results: note I updated the input data to degrees:

```
import cmath
import math

cityCoords = {
    1:(11.0036111,42.1025),
    2:(11.1086111,42.3738889)
    }

def spherical_cosines(coordDict):
    R = 6371;  # kilometers
    cities = list(coordDict.keys())
    n = len(cities)
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        for j in range(i + 1, n + 1):
            cityA = cities[i-1]
            lat1, lon1 = coordDict[cityA]
            cityB = cities[j-1]
            lat2, lon2 = coordDict[cityB]
            lat1_radians = math.radians(lat1)
            lat2_radians = math.radians(lat2)
            lon1_radians = math.radians(lon1)
            lon2_radians = math.radians(lon2)
            print('A={},{} B={},{}'.format(lat1_radians, lon1_radians, lat2_radians, lon2_radians))
            delta_lon_radians = math.radians(lon2-lon1)
            distance = cmath.acos(cmath.sin(lat1_radians) * cmath.sin(lat2_radians) + cmath.cos(lat1_radians) *
                        math.cos(lat2_radians) * cmath.cos(delta_lon_radians)) * R;
            print('spherical_cosines distance={}'.format(distance))


spherical_cosines(cityCoords)
```

**update**:
The code you posted is not producing the correct distance values.  Here's the first two cities using calcCityDistances and sperical cosines:

```
input loc=11003.6111, 42102.5
input loc=11108.6111, 42373.8889
radians A = 192.05631381917777,734.8329132074075
B=193.88890915251113,739.5740671363777
calcCityDistances distance = 8078.816781077703
input degrees A=11.0036111,42.1025 B=11.1086111,42.3738889
radians A=0.19204924330399503,0.7348272483209126
B=0.19388183901858905,0.7395638781792782
spherical_cosines> distance=(31.835225475974934+0j)
```

Units is kilometers.  Spherical cosines produces approximately the right value.  Is the code you're using the same as what you posted?  Notice the radians conversion doesn't seem to take into account that the input is thousandths of a degree

Comment: Thank you for you ansver :) but this does not solve my problem becouse your algorithm give same distance units between cities as mine so the result of TSP will be the same

Comment: I'm not getting the same values for the two methods. I updated the answer with output showing what I'm getting

Comment: Yeah you are right  i checked your calculations with google maps and the distances are correct. thank you. The question here is why than they have optimal path 6656 when it cannot be right result with theese distances my program calculated optimal path 845.171608273 which is really far away from their resulr

Comment: you're on the right track with 845 km.  I created a KML file from the 38 points, then did a really rough path in GE through them all and got 876 km.  There are two issues with the distance calc given on the web site: first, I don't think it expects thousandths of a degree inputs.  You can tell by the conversion to radians which is not correct.  The trig functions MUST have radians.  Second, even if you give the distance calculation function degrees (and radians is computed correctly), the distance is close but not correct (50 km <-> 31 km)